# Is there any proper example for LOGIN7 on TDS protocol?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, tds

Where can I find a proper example for LOGIN7 message? I can see an example for PRELOGIN at http://klonkers.blogspot.com/2015/01/making-something-useful-out-of-ms-tds.html

I could not find a proper example for LOGIN7.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the FAQ on asking a good question on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The MS-TDS documentation includes a section on [protocol examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/e48ebc47-2e95-4970-a116-da45862af90b).

In particular you're looking for the [4.2 Login Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/ce5ad23f-6bf8-4fa5-9426-6b0d36e14da2) example which includes information to help decode the following LOGIN7 packet:

```
 10 01 00 90 00 00 01 00 88 00 00 00 02 00 09 72 
 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 07 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 E0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 04 00 00 5E 00 08 00 
 6E 00 02 00 72 00 00 00 72 00 07 00 80 00 00 00 
 80 00 00 00 80 00 04 00 88 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 
 00 50 8B E2 B7 8F 88 00 00 00 88 00 00 00 88 00 
 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 00 6B 00 6F 00 73 00 74 00 
 6F 00 76 00 31 00 73 00 61 00 4F 00 53 00 51 00 
 4C 00 2D 00 33 00 32 00 4F 00 44 00 42 00 43 00
```

Comment: Already used this after completing prelogin and received response. But the subsequent login7 did not success. There is no proper examples or step by step details found anywhere.   I am using SQL 2012. The TDS to be used is 1.4. How to make the LOGIN7 message which will be accepted by the server ?.